# Bootstrap tabs transparent underline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to make the underline from the active / hovered tab transparent. But I didn't get it working. Anyone knows how to do this?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXJz.png
I want the red marked white line removed.
Setting blue border bottom color isn't the correct solution because I need it transparent/removed.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mULUv/6/

```
    border-color: #fff #fff transparent;
```

I guess I need something to do here.
But still don't get it working like I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only cover up borders in `css`, and since you do not want to set a blue color to overlap one of your borders, the only remaining (and quite tricky) way of achieving the effect you are looking for is to "build" the borders *block by block*.

The idea is to remove the bottom border from the `ul` container bar and add fillers between the tabs and after them that would have a bottom border. Then, the tabs which are not hovered nor active will have a bottom border displayed closing the gaps between fillers. Hovering or activating will cause the tab to lose the bottom border and to gain a right, left and top border. Using a custom css class such as your `.tab-advanced` this can be done safely without overwriting the built-in BootStrap classes.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mULUv/16/).

The html code to add the fillers changes the list to:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-advanced">
    <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li class="in-between-filler"></li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
    <li class="in-between-filler"></li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
    <li class="filler"></li>
</ul>
```

and the corresponding additional `css` is:

```
.tabs-advanced {
    display: table;
    border: none;
}

.tabs-advanced > li{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}

.tabs-advanced > li > a{
    margin-right: 0;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}

.tabs-advanced > li:not(.active):not(:hover) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-advanced > li.filler{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-advanced > li.in-between-filler{
    min-width: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could either do...

```
border: none;
```

or

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

(if you want a 1px line there still)

Comment: In what way does it not work? Could you possibly elaborate? Do you want a 0px border? Or a 1px border that can't be seen?

Comment: I want to bottom border completly removed/transparent like so:
http://i.imgur.com/qw6syrU.png
This line needs to be removed/transparent (red marked line): 
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/5589/jejb.png

Comment: Alright, that makes sense now. Try this resource, it may be of some help...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518642/how-do-i-remove-a-section-of-the-border-on-a-div-to-make-left-nav-look-seamless)