# Bootstrap Fade on Tab is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
            <div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1">Texts</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">Some text</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">Just fill this pace</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">Some more texts</div>
</div>
```

Fade is not working as I removed active ( I do not wish to any tab to be active on load so) how can I make fade in effect without using active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `active` from the `nav` but not on the `tab-content` .... To keep the content closed remove the class `in`:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
            <div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab1">Texts</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">Some text</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">Just fill this pace</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">Some more texts</div>
</div>
```

Check this **[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/wA6dqS5cJj)**

Comment: When we use tab there will be one line below tabs, can we remove that line?

Comment: I found answer for above question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173386/bootstrap-tabs-transparent-underline